# Azure Function app not logging correct severity levels

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I am trying to configure my logger and its logging levels in my Function App to only log Errors when in certain environments based on an environment variable. Currently no matter what it still logs things at a lower severity than error. I am not sure how to get this configuration to take effect. Any help would be great. My goal is only have logger.LogError() messages and up to up to show in my production environment.

```
        public static void ConfigureLogging(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        var outputTemplateString = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} ({SourceContext}){NewLine}{Exception}";
        var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplateString);

        string applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
        if (applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey != null)
        {
            var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            telemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey;
            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces);

            var environmentLogLevel = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogLevels), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment").ToLower());

            switch (environmentLogLevel)
            {
                case 1:
                    loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Debug();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Information();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Warning();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Error();
                    break;
                default:
                    loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Error();
                    break;
            }
        }

        Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();
        services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger)

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of the parsing? (Value of `environmentLogLevel`)

Comment: Do mind that the function runtime also creates lots of logging of level info do make sure you're looking at the right logs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all I actually got it to work as intended this morning. In my case my infrastructure is built with terraform, the logger cannot be configured at app start up, the host.json file needs to be overridden. To solve this issues I put an Environment variable in terraform file as so AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Default = var.loglevel. The I just set my my log levels for each environment to what level I wanted in the corresponding variable file.